# StrongLoop Arc Composer Doesn't Discover Models From Different Schema Than DBO

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a relational database on MSSQL, I've created this one on a different schema (titan) than DBO. When I try to retrieve the models from my database, the composer of strongloop arc only shows those tables that are currently saved on DBO schema but not my tables saved in my custom schema.

Any help might be useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For relational database discovery, LoopBack API allows you to supply schema and table. But the schema is not exposed by StrongLoop Arc. As a result, only default schema names are used by Arc. Please note dbo is the default schema name for mssql.

I suggest you open a feature request on github for StrongLoop Arc.